# How to post out the value of a radio button into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

I've been struggling to solve my issue.
so here it is, I was building a form that will insert new online games to my website via my admin panel, everything working perfect but then I added games categories, so when I upload a game, i can choose which category page it will be uploaded into...
So I was choosing a radio button for each category and I tried to bring the value of a specific category I ticked to MySQL using the method $_POST, and for some reason the game is uploaded to MySQL without an empty value under "game_category"...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="insert_form" action="insert_game.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="insert_form_title">
<h1>Insert New Game Here</h1>
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_name">Game name:</label>
<input type="text" name="game_name">
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_category">Game category:</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="game_category" value="action"<?php print $action_status; ?>/> <span>Action</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="game_category" value="sports"<?php print $sports_status; ?>/> <span>Sports</span>
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_keywords">Game keywords:</label>
<textarea name="game_keywords" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_image">Game image:</label>
<input type="file" name="game_image">
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_code">Game code:</label>
<input type="file" name="game_code">
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_file">Game flash file:</label>
<input type="file" name="game_file">
</div>

<div class="insert_form_inline">
<label class="insert_form_field" for="game_desc">Game description:</label>
<textarea name="game_desc" cols="60" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Game Now"></td>
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
include("../includes/connect.php");

$action_status = 'unchecked';
$sports_status = 'unchecked';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$game_name = $_POST['game_name'];
$game_category = $_POST['game_category'];
$game_keywords = $_POST['game_keywords'];
$game_image = $_FILES['game_image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['game_image']['tmp_name'];
$game_code = $_FILES['game_code']['name'];
$code_tmp = $_FILES['game_code']['tmp_name'];
$game_file = $_FILES['game_file']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['game_file']['tmp_name'];
$game_desc = $_POST['game_desc'];

if($game_name=='' or $game_category='' or $game_keywords=='' or $game_image=='' or $game_code=='' or $game_file=='' or $game_desc==''){

echo "<script>alert('Please enter all the fields below!')</script>";

exit();

}
else {

 $path = "../games/games_files/$game_name";

 mkdir("$path", 0777);

 move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/games_images/$game_image");

 move_uploaded_file($code_tmp,"$path/$game_code");

 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$path/$game_file");

 $insert_query = "insert into games (game_name,game_category,game_keywords,game_image,game_code,game_file,game_desc) values ('$game_name','$game_category','$game_keywords','$game_image','$game_code','$game_file','$game_desc')";

 if($game_category == 'action'){

 $action_status = 'checked';

 }else if($game_category == 'sports'){

 $sports_status = 'checked';

 }else if(mysql_query($insert_query)){

 echo "<script>alert('The Game Uploaded Successfully!')</script>";

 echo "<script>window.open('view_games.php','_self')</script>";

 }

}

}

?>

<?php } ?>
```

Help anyone? :(

Comment: I am not sure what value="action"<?php print $action_status; ?> part of your code does it may be causing an error because the value should just be "action" EDIT: I just scrolled and saw unchecked. okay

Comment: So what is still wrong with my code? :o

Comment: I don't know how this script will work based on the way it is been written. I advice you put all the PHP related code above the HTML code

Comment: Thanks Lepanto, will try that now, but I don't think its matter wether the php code is above or bellow my HTML code...

Comment: It does matter how you write the script. Because you have use `<?php print $action_status; ?>` in HTML where `$action_status` gets value from PHP script below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David try updating the script as below.

```
 $insert_query = "insert into games (game_name,game_category,game_keywords,game_image,game_code,game_file,game_desc) values ('$game_name','$game_category','$game_keywords','$game_image','$game_code','$game_file','$game_desc')";
 if($game_category == 'action'){
   $action_status = 'checked';
 }else if($game_category == 'sports'){
     $sports_status = 'checked';
 }

 if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
   echo "<script>alert('The Game Uploaded Successfully!')</script>";
   echo "<script>window.open('view_games.php','_self')</script>";
 }
```

And also, in the big `if` condition, you can see that you have missed one `=` sign in **$game_category=''**.

So correct following

`if($game_name=='' or $game_category='' or $game_keywords=='' or $game_image=='' or $game_code=='' or $game_file=='' or $game_desc==''){`

to

`if($game_name=='' or $game_category=='' or $game_keywords=='' or $game_image=='' or $game_code=='' or $game_file=='' or $game_desc==''){`

Comment: Thanks! will try that in a moment and will inform you shortly ;)

Comment: Still, I get no value under "game_category" in phpmyadmin... :(

Comment: Can you put `echo $insert_query; exit;` before `if($game_category == 'action'){` and see if you get value for game_category?

Comment: It doesn't work... after I submit the game its echoing this: "insert into games (game_name,game_category,game_keywords,game_image,game_code,game_file,game_desc) values ('Test Game','','hshs','1starship_large.jpg','1starship.html','1starship.swf','hsjsjsjk')" note: the 'hsjsjsjk' is a dummy text for the description of the game...

Comment: Remove that echo statement and see the last edit of my answer above

Comment: Thanks mate, will try now again ;)

Comment: It Worked like a charm!!! Thanks buddy :) However it seems that uploading a game takes now a bit too long :o

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:
1. Create an "if" statement like the following code:

```
if($game_category == '3d'){

$three_d_status = 'checked';

}else if($game_category == 'action'){

$action_status = 'checked';

}else if($game_category == 'adventure'){

$adventure_status = 'checked';

}
```

2. Then, create for each field you want to use with a "radio button" a line like this:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="game_category" value="3d"<?php print $three_d_status; ?>/><span>3D</span>
```

That's it, You are ready to go :)